# Kendo menu item overlaped tabstrip items in layout.cshtml

Tags: telerik, .net-8.0

Kendo menu item overlaped tabstrip items in _layout.cshtml (dot net core 8.0)
[before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOCGO.png)
[during render body in Tabstrip2 (about 6 seconds)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK6gG.png) 
The code of _layout.cshtml is:

```
<body>
    <header>
        @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
            .Name("Menu")
            .Items(items =>
            {
                items.Add()
                .Text("Menu")
                .Items(children =>
                {
                    children.Add().Text("Menu item 1").Action("Profile", "Admin");
                });
                items.Add()
                .Text("In work");
            })
        )

        @(
            Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                .Name("tabstrip")
                .Animation(animation =>
                    animation.Open(effect =>
                        effect.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
                .Items(tabstrip =>
                {
                    tabstrip.Add().Text("Tabstrip1").Action("Profile", "Admin");
                    tabstrip.Add().Text("Tabstrip2").Action("Start", "Admin");
                    tabstrip.Add().Text(" Tabstrip3").SpriteCssClasses("close-img").Action("Finish", "Admin");
                })
        )
    
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/datatables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.datatables.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

I tried many things, but nothing help.
I'll expect fix overlap.